# Where did texture paint in UV editor go?

Tags: texturing

[image]
Before 2.8, it was possible to change the mode of the UV editor to "draw" (I don't know the exact name) and thereby texture paint within the UV editor. The option has disappeared in 2.8. How can I draw in the UV editor or image editor?

I used Windows Paint to make the thin lines, but we don't have the various texture types there, so it's not an alternative solution.

**Solution:**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2.80 the Image editor is now separated from the UV editor. So you need to switch to that.

[image]

edited to add:

Create a new image to paint on then select the brush icon and start drawing.....

In the **Image Editor**, **Image** menu choose the **New** option to create an image layer to draw on.

[image]

Comment: Yup, I know that. Where can I draw in these modes? As for now, I can only draw on the mesh itself, but not the faces that are made 2D in one of these editors. How can I draw in the editors you showed me?

Comment: I have added an image to my earlier post.

Comment: Ah, I've overseen that there is a paint option in the top left corner.